# @font-face declaration works on Firefox but not Safari/WebKit?

Tags: css, firefox, safari, webkit, font-face

The following @font-face declaration works perfectly well on Firefox (Mac) but not Safari/WebKit:

```
@font-face {
 font-family:MyGaramond;
 src:local("Garamond Premier Pro"), /* Full name */
     local("GaramondPremrPro"), /* Postscript name */
     url("GaramondPremrPro.otf") format("opentype"); /* Fallback */
}

h2 {
 font-family:MyGaramond, sans-serif !important;
}
```

To clarify, I've also tried:

```
@font-face {
 font-family:MyGaramond;
 src:local("Garamond Premier Pro"), /* Full name */
     local("GaramondPremrPro"), /* Postscript name */
     url("GaramondPremrPro.otf"); /* Fallback */
}

h2 {
 font-family:MyGaramond, sans-serif !important;
}
```

, with/without quotes, etc.

Has anyone else experienced this, and if so, how did you fix it? That this isn't working is really baffling (and a tad irritating...).

Comment: Tried the top code here in a quick simple .html I made and it worked okay in Sarafi 4.0.4 under Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think webkit still has some problems with opentype. How does opera handle it?

Comment: Nevermind. Not sure what the problem was, but I used TrueType Pro to convert from OpenType to OpenType and now it works fine. Maybe it was a malformed file.

Answer (score 0):

I always use the @font-face Generator from font squirrel, never had any browser issues that way.

Check the site: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator